# My app can send a request, but could not receive a response

Tags: java, android, sockets, serversocket

i need to send request to the server and the server need to respond back a text string. Now when i click a button on android app it send request to my server and i can view it but i could not see the respond in the android app. it should be displaying the text in a textarea.
 below is my code in my android app.

```
package monitor;


import java.util.Enumeration;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.text.format.Formatter;
import android.util.Log;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.Reader;
import java.io.Writer;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import android.os.Bundle;
import java.net.SocketException;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;


public class welcome extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Socket s;
    private Button status;
private Button client;
private Button log;
private TextView text;
private PrintWriter writer;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    OutputStreamWriter request = null;
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.welcome);
    setupVariables();
    final TextView mTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);

    status.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            Thread t = new Thread(){

                @Override
                public void run(){
                    //String serverMsg=null;
                    //String text = "test";
                    try {
                        System.out.println("Starting Connection");
                        Socket s = new Socket("10.0.2.2", 25000);
                        System.out.println("Connection DONE");
                        DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());
                        dos.writeUTF("stat");
                        dos.flush();

                      // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Message sent to the server",
                     //Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        //Intent intent=new Intent(welcome.this,status.class); 
                       //startActivity(intent);
                     InputStream is = s.getInputStream();
                        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
                        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
                        text = br.readLine();

                        dos.close();
                        s.close();
                        System.out.println("Closing socket");
                    }
                    catch (UnknownHostException e){
                        System.out.println("There was an Unknown Erorr:");
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        System.out.println("There was an IOException:");
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                   mTextView.setText(text);

                }

            };
            t.start(); }
    });

    client.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            Thread t = new Thread(){
                @Override
                public void run(){
                    try {
                        System.out.println("Starting Connection");
                        Socket s = new Socket("10.0.2.2", 25000);
                        System.out.println("Connection DONE");
                        DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());
                        dos.writeUTF("client");
                        InputStream is = s.getInputStream();
                        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
                        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
                        text = br.readLine();
                        dos.close();
                        s.close();
                        System.out.println("Closing socket");
                    }
                    catch (UnknownHostException e){
                        System.out.println("There was an Unknown Erorr:");
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        System.out.println("There was an IOException:");
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                   mTextView.setText(text);
                        dos.flush();
                        dos.close();
                        s.close();
                        System.out.println("Closing socket");
                    }
                    catch (UnknownHostException e){
                        System.out.println("There was an Unknown Erorr:");
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        System.out.println("There was an IOException:");
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            };
            t.start();
        }
    });
    log.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            Intent intent=new Intent(welcome.this,MainActivity.class); // redirecting to LoginActivity.
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

}
 public void onBackPressed() {
// empty so nothing happens
    }
private void setupVariables() {

    status = (Button) findViewById(R.id.wel2);
    client = (Button) findViewById(R.id.wel3);
    log = (Button) findViewById(R.id.iog);

}
}
```

Below is my server code.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.lang.Runtime;
import java.util.Enumeration;
import java.io.IOException;

public class fyp4 {

private static Socket socket;

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
{
try
    {
        int port = 25000;
        ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
        System.out.println("Server Started and listening to the port 25000");
       while(true)
        {   

            //Reading the message from the client
            socket = serverSocket.accept();
            InputStream is = socket.getInputStream();
            InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
            //Socket newSock = s.accept();
            String number = br.readLine();
            number = number.trim();
            System.out.println("Message received from client is "+number);
            OutputStream os = socket.getOutputStream();
            OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(os);
            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(osw);
            bw.write(returnMessage);
            System.out.println("Message sent to the client is "+returnMessage);
           bw.flush();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    finally
    {
        try
        {
            socket.close();
        }
        catch(Exception e){}
    }
}    
}
```

Comment: You know how threads work, right? You don't receive anyhting because by the time that code is reached, the server reads the data. When it writes, the client has already closed the input stream and moved on

Comment: could u suggest a way to read the response? i even tried with two theard one for send and one for receiving but still could not get the response